# check laravel syntax error in using helper function in where condition when join tha table

Tags: function, where-clause

**Can be use helper function in where condition when join the table**

```
            DB::table($table)
            ->join('application_seen', $table.'.'.'formid', '=', 'application_seen.applicationid')
            ->where('userid','=', nametouserid($table.'.'.'name'))
            ->get()
            ->count();
```

I checked the helper function which used in where condition, that is working. when i use string value like "706" joining is working fine, so my question is can be use helper function in where condition if yes then how. please help me
thanks

Comment: You can place this inside a method and if you wish to place it inside a helpers file. But i suggest taking a look at models & eloquents: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent